# Keyboard / mouse freeze

Tags: keyboard, mouse, freeze

Pretty much on a daily basis the keyboard & mouse on my Dell PC stop responding. I have left the PC on for over 10 minutes but still no response so I have to power on / off. Keyboard / mouse then work fine.

I did have 2 mice attached to the PC but I have now removed one to see if this makes any difference. CPU temperatures are 51C & 48C - dont know whether this is normal or high?

OS is Windows 7.

Adrian

Comment: Could be power saving settings are funky. You don't give much detail about this freeze, e.g. not accessible from the network, whether there is hard disk activity, etc.

Comment: Did you try rebooting? ;)

Comment: As mentioned below is the entire computer frozen or just the peripherals? A way to check is have sound or a video playing when it freezes.

Comment: I can answer this - it's the whole computer; the clock in the bottom right corner is the simplest indicator! It doesn't change. I work with Adrian so I'm commenting for him :)

Comment: Does it work OK in safe mode?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the entire computer is unresponsive, the fault could be pretty much anything.

You say about the temperatures - these are not *that* high, however in thermal situations, the computer should just shutdown without warning - not freeze.

If I was you, I would perform a [Memory test](http://www.memtest.org), check seating on components such as memory and wireless cards (they can become disloged slighty), and also run hardware diagnostics from the vendor of the hard drive.

You can never jump to conclusions on situations like this, but I have to say that I find, 80+% of the time, especially with laptops, the problem is the hard drive and changing it solves problems like this.

Comment: For whatever its worth, I had a Dell Inspiron a couple of years ago with overheating problems that froze as described by the asker when overheating while running Ubuntu (but shut down properly with Windows).